# Can you help me on a proof with Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis

Let $G$ be some collection of Lebesgue measurable subsets E of $R^2$ such that $\lambda(E) > 0$. Define $G_{n} = \{  E \in C : \lambda(E \cap [-n,n]) \geq 1/n\}$. Show that $G \subseteq \bigcup_{k = 1}^{\infty} G_n$

Let $E \in G$. Then E is Lebesgue measurable and $\lambda(E) > 0$. Then there is a $0 < \epsilon \leq 1$ and a  bounded open interval $J$, such that $\epsilon \lambda(J) < \lambda(E \cap J)$. Then I was going to use the Archemdian Property, next; there is an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon \lambda(J) < \lambda(E \cap J)$. Could I conclude that $\lambda(E \cap [-n,n]) > \frac{1}{n}$ ? Can you give out only hints please?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Let $E \in G$. If $\lambda (E) <\infty$ then $\lambda (E)=\lim \lambda (E\cap [-n,n])$ so there exists $n_0$ such that $\lambda (E\cap [-n,n]) \geq \frac {\lambda (E)} 2$ for $n \geq n_0$. Can you finish?

(The case $\lambda (E) =\infty$ is simpler).

Comment: So for the finite case, should that be $\lambda(E)/2$? Also, I'm not sure. How does this imply it is grater than $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: $\mu$ was a typo. If $n$ is large enough then $\lambda (E) >\frac  1 n$. We just want some $n$ such that $E \in G_n$ right? @suunySide